# How to show the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,y_0)} \frac{y}{x}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $y_0>0$ be a positive real number. I Know that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,y_0)} \frac{y}{x}$ diverges to infinity by intuition. But how do I prove it rigorously?

What I was thinking is if $c$ is a given real number then, we have to find one $\delta>0$ such that if $\sqrt{(x^2+(y-y_0)^2}<\delta$ then $\frac{y}{x}>c$. The problem is I could not construct such a $\delta$. What will be the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't diverge to infinity (though it still diverges, but you can get it to both $\infty$ and $-\infty$ by considering different paths), but its absolutely value does, and this can easily be shown by noticing that

$$\left\lvert\frac{y}{x}\right\rvert=\frac{\lvert y\rvert}{\sqrt{x^2}}\geq\frac{\lvert y\rvert}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-y_0)^2}}.$$

Choosing

$$\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{1+\lvert y_0\rvert}{c}\right\}$$

we then have that

$$\lvert y\rvert\leq\lvert y-y_0\rvert+\lvert y_0\rvert\leq\sqrt{x^2+(y-y_0)^2}+\lvert y_0\rvert\leq1+\lvert y_0\rvert$$

and so also

$$\left\lvert\frac{y}{x}\right\rvert\geq\frac{1+\lvert y_0\rvert}{\delta}\geq c,$$

which shows that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y_0)}\left\lvert\frac{y}{x}\right\rvert=\infty.$$

Comment: You are right it diverges both sides..